# Copy a cell with format - Google Sheet

Tags: google-sheets, format, copy

I'm going to become crazy. I've now spent hours looking for this simple answer but there is always something going wrong.
I have a Google sheet document, on this document, there is an half empty half full table. On another sheet, I have another table but full empty. I would like to put a formula or a script that could copy what is already in the first table and what will come after.
To make it clearer, i have a table organized with weeks and another with months.
I don't want a full optimized thing. Just something to copy a cell to another with content and format (the format is just the background).
Thanks for your help.

I spent like 10 hours on many sites to find the answer but I didn't managed to find one.
I would like a full explaination of how to do because I'm not really skilled with all this.

Edit :
To answer back:

The two images below are what I have now. I want to be able to copy one cell from the first table to one ine the second table.

For example : I want B2 to be equal to H2, here it's already true but i copy and paste it myself.

I want to fill the second table with a formula or a script that will copy what is input in the first table.

I hope it's clearer

[image]

[image]

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, I cannot understand your question. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the sample input and output situations you expect? First, I would like to correctly understand your question.

Comment: What have you tried so far? Whenever possible, you need to include a minimal example that reproduces the issue. You can also include the expected behavior, the actual behavior, and how they differ, that would be helpful as well. Please visit [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) have some tips on how to write a question, so the community will be able to help you out in a better way.